# Java openConnection setRequestProperty not setting Authentication Header

Tags: java, http-headers, httpurlconnection

I am building an HTTP connection and setting the headers I need.

At this point, I'm setting three headers.  They are Authorization, Accept, and User-Agent.

I'm invoking the .setRequestProperty() method for each of the headers.  For some reason, the Accept and User-Agent headers get set, and the Authorization header does not get set.

Using the .getRequestProperty() method, I see the Accept and User-Agent headers are set as I would expect, but the Authorization header return "null".  The .getRequestProperties() method returns the two that were set, but no Authorization.

I've also tried the .addRequestProperty() method and it gives the same result (2 work but Authorization does not).

It does not matter in which order I issue the .setRequestProperty() methods, whether Authorization is first, middle, or last.  Authorization and only Authorization returns null.

I can set other headers such as "AuthorizationX" or "Random-Header" and they set just fine.  I've changed the value I pass along with the Authorization header, not only trying my actual correct authorization value but also trying other random strings.

I have also invoked the .setRequestMethod() method before and after the .setRequestProperty() method, as I've seen some examples on the Internet that shows setting that after the headers.  It has no effect on the connection.

For some reason, the Authorization header will not take!

In addition to this, the connection does work just fine, as I connect to my server and the server returns, you guessed it, "401 Not Authorized".

What does it take to get the connection properties to accept "Authorization" as a valid header?  What else can I possibly check?

Comment: I think you might need an https connection

Comment: I am actually using HTTPS.

Comment: I was able to set up a test server (Charles) to hit against so I could see the headers being received on the server.  My Authorization header was being sent and it was being sent properly.  However, the .getRequestProperties() and getRequestProperty() methods still do not return a value for the "Authorization" header (it always returns null).  Other headers that I set are returned as expected.  Is there something magic about the "Authorization" header, that cause these two methods to not return actual data?  It sure is misleading when trying to validate an authorization failure.